# Why is my Recylerview isn't displaying any elements?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So, I am trying to randomly fetch 4 key-value Pairs from object class **ImageStore.kt** and display it in the Fragment **PractiseFragment.kt** with the help of adapter class **PractiseAdapter.kt** Below are the codes of all the classes

1. ImageStore.kt

   ```
   object ImageStore {

   private val _imagesNamesMap = hashMapOf(
        R.drawable.africa to Pair("Africa","Afrika"),
        R.drawable.asia to Pair("Asia","Azija"),
        R.drawable.europe to Pair("Europe","Europa"),
        R.drawable.antartica to Pair("Antarctica","Antarktida"),
        R.drawable.airplane to Pair("Aeroplane","Lėktuvas"),
        R.drawable.apple1 to Pair("Apple","Obuolys"),
        R.drawable.key to Pair("Key","raktas"),
        R.drawable.sleep to Pair("to sleep","miegoti"),
        R.drawable.shopping to Pair("to shop","apsipirkti"),
        R.drawable.cinemascreen to Pair("to watch a movie","Žiūrėti filmą"),
        R.drawable.goshopping to Pair("I go shopping","aš einu apsipirkti"),
        R.drawable.what1 to Pair("What is it?","Kas tai?"),
        R.drawable.japanesefood to Pair("Japanese food","Japonų maistas"),
        R.drawable.hotcoffee to Pair("hot coffee","karšta kava"),
        R.drawable.eat to Pair("to eat","valgyti"),
        R.drawable.ofcourse to Pair("Of course","Žinoma"),
        R.drawable.rice to Pair("rice","ryžiai"),
        R.drawable.soup1 to Pair("soup","sriuba"),
        R.drawable.bread1 to Pair("Bread","Duona"),
        R.drawable.water1 to Pair("water","vanduo"),
        R.drawable.glass1 to Pair("a glass","stiklinė"),
        R.drawable.apple1 to Pair("apple","obuolys"),   
    )
    val imagesNamesMap: Map<Int, Pair<String, String>>
        get() = _imagesNamesMap.toList().shuffled().take(4).toMap()
   ```

   }

so as you can see the code, I want t odisplay random any 4 key-value pairs in the Fragment. Below is the code written for PractiseFragment

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
        binding.recyclerViewPractise.layoutManager = layoutManager
        

        practiseAdapter = PractiseAdapter(binding.btnShuffle,recyclerViewPractise)

        binding.recyclerViewPractise.adapter = practiseAdapter
        practiseAdapter.initsetRecyclerView(recyclerViewPractise)
```

This is the code for PractiseAdapter.kt

```
@SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
class PractiseAdapter(
    btnShuffle: AppCompatButton,
    recyclerViewPractise: RecyclerView,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PractiseAdapter.PractiseViewHolder>() {

    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var anyCardIsGreen = false
    private var selectedImageResource = -1
    private var selectedImageName = ""
    private var previousSelectedImageResource = -1
    private var previousSelectedImageName = ""
    var imageResources: MutableList<Int>
    var imageNames1: MutableList<Pair<String,String>>

    init {
        imageResources = mutableListOf()
        imageNames1 = mutableListOf()
            btnShuffle.setOnClickListener {
                shuffleCards()
            }
    }

    private fun shuffleCards() {

        imageResources = ImageStore.imagesNamesMap.keys.toList().shuffleList().toMutableList()

        imageNames1= imageResources.mapNotNull { it ->
            val pair = ImageStore.imagesNamesMap[it]
            pair?.let { Pair(pair.first, pair.second) }
        }.toList().shuffleList().toMutableList()


        // Reset the selected image and name
        selectedImageResource = -1
        selectedImageName = ""
        previousSelectedImageResource = -1
        previousSelectedImageName = ""

        // Reset the background color of cardImage views to white
        resetCardImageBackgroundToWhite()


        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun initsetRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView
    }

    private fun resetCardImageBackgroundToWhite() {
        // Iterate through the card views and reset the background color of cardImage to white
        for (position in 0 until imageResources.size) {

            val holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position) as? PractiseViewHolder
            holder?.cardImagePractise?.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val GREEN_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#ABEBC6")
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PractiseViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_practise_cards, parent, false)

        return PractiseViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = imageResources.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PractiseViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val imageResource = imageResources[position]
        val imageName1 = imageNames1[position]


        holder.imageViewPractise.setImageResource(imageResource)
        holder.textViewPractise.text = imageName1.first
        holder.textViewPractise1.text = imageName1.second

        holder.cardImagePractise.setOnClickListener {
            selectedImageResource = imageResource
            previousSelectedImageResource = selectedImageResource
            selectedImageName = ""
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            holder.cardImagePractise.setCardBackgroundColor(GREEN_COLOR)
        }
        holder.cardTextPractise.setOnClickListener {
            if (selectedImageResource == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    it.context,
                    "Please select an image card first.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            } else {
                selectedImageName = imageNames1[position].first
                previousSelectedImageName = selectedImageName
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        val nameColor = if(imageNames1[position].first ==selectedImageName){
            if(ImageStore.imagesNamesMap[selectedImageResource]?.first==selectedImageName){
                Toast.makeText(
                    holder.itemView.context,
                    "Correct name selected!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                anyCardIsGreen=true
                holder.cardTextPractise.setBackgroundColor(GREEN_COLOR) // Set green background for the name card
                Color.GREEN
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    holder.itemView.context,
                    "Wrong name selected!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                Color.RED
            }
        } else {
              holder.cardTextPractise.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
              Color.WHITE
        }
        holder.cardTextPractise.setBackgroundColor(nameColor)

        // Check if the card is green and set anyCardIsGreen accordingly

    }
    class PractiseViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val cardImagePractise: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImagePractise)
        val cardTextPractise: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTextPractise)
        val imageViewPractise: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPractise)
        val textViewPractise: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPractise)
        val textViewPractise1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPractise1)

    }
}
```

Comment: i think you initialize recyclerview later so try ```practiseAdapter.initsetRecyclerView(recyclerViewPractise)
binding.recyclerViewPractise.adapter = practiseAdapter``` swaping these lines

Comment: Nope , it's not working. The app get's stuck at splashscreen

Comment: Can you share more detailed code with splash screen as well

Comment: Please, consider adding your errors stack trace from the Logcat. Without an error / warning it's difficult to help you out.